# Cleaning up difficult arpeggios

Tags: notation

I'm having a hard time on deciding how to clean this up (piano in 5/4):

[image: arpeggios]

This is a possibility:

[image]

But it's so ugly. And not necessarily more readable I think. But it is simpler.
What do you think is the best way to clean this up?

Comment: Grace note the Ab/G#.

Comment: A third stave perhaps for the top line?  The alignment of rests and notes is what strikes me as awkward and the third stave would clear that up.  Just a thought.

Comment: The second one isn't readable at all. It looks like you have 6 beats on the top staff and 5 on the bottom one. (Ah... I just realized the second "quarter rest" is actually an arpeggio sign!)  And why are the G#-B half-note heads smaller than the C half-note that follows them?

Comment: Yes, the 2nd arpeggio is really unclear. The noteheads are smaller to indicate they should be played less loud/unaccented. But thats's not clear apparently...

Comment: I often suppress rests in secondary voices if they are not necessary. Could that help clean it up? What about putting the whole note G in the treble clef in the bass clef instead (I.e., with leger lines) and either leave it to the player to choose fingering or put a "with r. h." notation on it?

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm gonna go for your suggestion @ToddWilcox

Comment: Notate the G natural so it appears on third leger line above the bass-clef staff rather than within the treble-clef staff. That way the treble clef staff is kept clear for the top notes of your arpeggiated chord. This will be much easier to read.

Comment: Adding r.h. next to the note on the third ledger line would be enough I assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start with the second image since it is simpler to begin with.

There are a few issues I noticed:

1. The second chord is smaller in size.
2. The proximity of G and G# on the score.
3. The rest above the first chord is confusing.

I would move the first chord entirely to the lower score, even if the upper note (G) is meant to be played by the right hand:

[image]

Alternatively you may consider changing G to a 1/4 note, which would sound the same (if playing with pedal is assumed):

[image]